# Sticky footer not moving to bottom and page is too long

Tags: html, css, wordpress

It seems that I can't get my sticky footer to work! I have looked at multiple stackoverflow articles along with a few examples and can't get to the same outcome.

Edit: I do not want the footer to be fixed. I am wanting it to be at the bottom of the screen if the content is not sufficient to push it down, if it does get pushed down then to let it.

Here is my full CSS code: http://collabedit.com/wegv8

Here is my relevant CSS code:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -42px;
  padding: 0 0 42px;
}

footer {
  height: 42px;
}
```

And relevant HTML:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="row wrap">

        <div class="col-sm-12 blog-main">

            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile; endif;
            ?>

        </div> <!-- /.blog-main -->

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div> <!-- /.row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This can be best viewed at http://whatloop.com/wpTheme/just-another-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your footer css to this.

```
footer {
height: 42px;
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

or add this to your blog-footer class

```
bottom:0;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
```

Comment: Hi Rafraf, I don't want it to be fixed. I would like it to be at the bottom of the screen if the page is short similar to the one I linked, but if the page is long just sit at the bottom as it typically would.

Comment: try on your blog-footer class

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

Comment: So close! But it doesn't scroll down, it just sticks itself at the bottom and stays there.

Comment: wait @BrydonMcCluskey . tryin to figure out that now.

Comment: you might want to try adding height on your content after the masthead. I think that's causing the problem.

Comment: I'm still not seeing any improvements on my side. Maybe I am doing it wrong, though..

Comment: Try exploring this jiddle. Hope it helps https://jsfiddle.net/digamber89/mpvv79jq/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for your footer, you'll want to add something like this:

```
position: fixed; 
z-index: 1000;
```

That will ensure that your footer is omnipresent upon scrolling, and overlaps the page content that scrolls.

Hope this works!

Comment: Hey TCharb, thanks for the comment but I do not want it to be fixed. I want it to be at the bottom of the screen when the content doesn't push it down, but if it does get pushed down then to let it.

Answer (score 0):

add one class on `blog-masthead` after `container`

Apply this css

```
.className{
  min-height: calc(100% - 247px);
}
```

Comment: Hi Laljii! This method extended the black box considerably but did not move it.